# Making a navbar of logo + nav + social

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the text in my navbar and my social links too, but I just can't. I've searched on google, tried everything, it doesn't work. I'm a beginner btw. I've tried every solution I've found on google for about 1hr and all I did is getting mad. damn
I don't get it. In the snippet everything works fine, it is centered as I want. But in my PC, it looks like this: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8UM7.png)
Can you explain to me why does it happen?

```css
//Header 
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

//bara navigatie
#bara {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#bara-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #111111;
}


.butoane ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.butoane li {
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 4em;
        font-size: 1em;
}

.butoane li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    width: 11em;
    margin-left: 45em;
    float: left;
}

.social {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
            <div id="bara-wrap">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo" />
                    <nav id="bara">
                        <ul class="butoane">
                            <li><a href="#" class="home">home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="about">about</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="skills">skills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="contact">contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                <ul class="social">
                    <li class="facebook">facebook</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: There is quite a bit wrong with this. Does this help you? https://jsfiddle.net/me4fy37k/

Comment: No, it looks like this now.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/r3uh2

Answer (score 0):

use this one i made some changes in your html and css.

### html

```
<header id="header" style="opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
        <div id="bara-wrap">                    
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo" />
            <nav id="bara">
                <ul class="butoane">
                    <li><a href="#" class="home">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="skills">skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="contact">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="social">
                    <li class="facebook">facebook</li>
                </ul>   
            </nav>                      
        </div>
</header>
```

### css

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

//bara navigatie
#bara {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#bara-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #111111;
}


.butoane ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.butoane li {
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 4em;
        font-size: 1em;
}

.butoane li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
    width: 11em;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.social {

    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: what you getting the result actually just post images after changing with my code

Comment: I've resolved it. Thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the butoane class and copy the posted right now css file and paste it into your css file....

```
//Header 
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

//bara navigatie
#bara {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#bara-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #111111;
}
img{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
    margin-top: 25px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 4em;
    font-size: 1em;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
.logo {
    width: 11em;
    margin-left: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.social {

    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```